# Ubuntu VirtualBox - Black screen after *ERROR* failed to send host log message

Tags: boot, virtualbox, windows-10

I'm running Linux ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox 6.1 and I'm on windows 10. For the past weeks, it worked almost perfectly, I just once had a problem with a black screen but it was just a video memory issue.
When I tried to open it today for the first time after a week, the boot-up prompt displayed the following error message  :
`[drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* failed to send host log message`
The ubuntu logo starts rotating, it disapears and I get a black screen.

I read a lot of advice on forums today, but I still can't figure it out. So far, I tried:

- Changing the display settings from VMSVGA to VboxVGA or VboxSVGA. I don't get this error in the prompt anymore, but I get an alert "invalid setting detected". It also leads to a black screen after the boot-up. I also tried to find help with that, but it failed. For the rest of these steps, I went back to the VMSVGA graphic controler.
- Turned off / on Windows Hypervisor Platform, Virtual Machine Platform in Windows Features.
- I apparently didn't had access to Hyper-V, so I downloaded it. I first tried to disable it using the command lines
  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
  `DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
  I went to check on Windows Features after restarting my pc and Hyper-V was downloaded but still activated. So I just unchecked the Hyper-V box from Windows Features. This also didn't do anything to the error message.
- Increased video memory to 128Mb, and double my disk space up to 64Gb
- Disable DeviceGuard with gpdedit.msc, but my system seemingly doesn't have it  (it's Windows 10 Pro only from what I read, I'm running Windows 10 Family). I also disabled Windows Defender's Core Isolation.

[Also, when I scroll to the bottom of my system informations, I have 4 lines related to hyper-v. The value (in the second column) is "yes", as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTYEq.png)
I think that this only shows if my system has the required configuration to use hyper-v though.

I have no clue what do to next as I'm very new to this type of environment. All the code I'm working with for a project is in this system and I really don't want to lose it in the process.
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Any update on this? I'm experiencing the same issues and tried the same steps. I'm running VirtualBox 7.0.2. I also tried to revert to a previous version of Virtualbox and that did not help.